# How to find mode of a multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, syntax, classification, mode

I have a multidimensional array

```
 ,,1
    [,1] [,2]        
 [1,] "0"  "a"    
 [2,] "1"  "a"    
 [3,] "1"  "b"
 [2,] "1"  "c"    
 [3,] "1"  "c"
 ,,2
    [,1] [,2]        
 [1,] "0"  "a"    
 [2,] "1"  "a"    
 [3,] "1"  "a"
 [2,] "0"  "b"    
 [3,] "0"  "c"
```

i just want to find the mode, if the first column is "1" for every group data.
For this multidimensional array, i want output maybe like this

```
 ,,1
 c
 ,,2
 a
```

or

```
[1] c
[2] a
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array looks like this:

```r
set.seed(1)
vec <- sample(c(0:3, letters[1:3]), 5 * 2 * 3, replace = TRUE)
dim(vec) <- c(5, 2, 3)
vec
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] "0"  "a" 
#> [2,] "3"  "c" 
#> [3,] "c"  "2" 
#> [4,] "0"  "b" 
#> [5,] "1"  "1" 
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] "2"  "1" 
#> [2,] "2"  "b" 
#> [3,] "0"  "b" 
#> [4,] "a"  "1" 
#> [5,] "a"  "c" 
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] "0"  "0" 
#> [2,] "c"  "b" 
#> [3,] "a"  "a" 
#> [4,] "a"  "a" 
#> [5,] "0"  "1"
```

Then you can find the most common entry in each slice of the array by doing:

```
apply(vec, 3, function(x) names(rev(sort(table(x))))[1])
#> [1] "c" "b" "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>